# Telling *.csproj formats apart

Tags: c#, .net, xml, visual-studio-2017, .net-core

I have an application that needs to parse the `ProjectReference` elements from `*.csproj` files. It could do this well with the old ([.net](/questions/tagged/.net)) format where I used the `Name` element to get the name of a project:

```
<ProjectReference Include="..\MyProject\MyProject.csproj">
  <Project>{guid..}</Project>
  <Name>MyProject</Name>
</ProjectReference>
```

The new format however ([.net-core](/questions/tagged/.net-core)) makes it crash now because there is no `Name` element anymore.

I found a few differences between both files but I'm not sure which one I should use tell that I'm working with the new core-file. The differences are:

- the new format does not contain xml declaration
- the root element starts with the `<Project Sdk=` attribute and does not contain any default namespace wheres the old one has `xmlns="` declared
- the `ProjectReference` element does not contain any children

Which property would be the most reliable way to recognize the core-file like Visual Studio does? Am I on the right track or is there any other criteria I should use to tell the file formats apart?

Comment: Why not just take the name from the destination project file instead? That would work for both types.

Comment: @DavidG true, this would certainly work and I actually might implement it like this later but I'd like to still know how to properly recognize the new file in case I would need some other information later and implement it in two different modules.

Comment: In that case I would probably use Project Sdk.

Comment: SDK can also be used to resolve arbitrary MSBuild sdks from NuGet in VS 15.6+, even for classic projects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using MSBuild to evaluate the project file, the sdk sets the `UsingMicrosoftNETSdk` property to `true`.

If you are only use XML based tooling to read the file, you can check if a `<TargetFramework>` or `<TargetFrameworks>` (plural) property (inside a `<PropertyGroup>`).

This is the same mechanism that visual studio uses to determine whether the new or classic project system is used for the project (see [Opening With CPS](https://github.com/dotnet/project-system/blob/fd277ab6029e324d0f81d4ddefd76dde90a6a67a/docs/opening-with-cps.md) document).

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned that I'm using the `XDocument` for reading it. This is definitely the best way to recognize the new format. Just out of curiosity, how would I use MSBuild to get such a list? I don't see any switches that could do this.

Comment: E.g. using the msbuild (Microsoft.Build.*) nuget packages and their api, but this is rather complicated to set up.. the property is set on the project during static evaluation.